# Find the limit as n approaches infinity of $\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!\cdot e^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the limit of:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!\cdot e^n}$$

I've tried to use the binomial formula but that didn't work out well.Also i tried to upper bound  the sequence using e's aproximations(the infinite series and the normal definition )

Comment: Can you please include the work you tried?

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: That would work very well but i am looking for a solution without it.Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, include the constraints on the tools in your Post
.